# Best way to concatenate an address in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows, location, concatenation

What I want to do is that if I enter an address such as

22-40 W 77th St, New York, NY 10024

I get

"W+77th+St,+New+York,+NY+10024/"

I feel like I am over complicating this...

Comment: do you have any code? How are you initially getting the address?

Comment: `str.replace(' ', '+')`? Good luck figuring out a rule that can handle detecting `22-40` as something to remove, or weird things like `123 East Street West`

Comment: Hm, the goal is to sort of enter the address and then from there you click lets say a button "go" and it will concatenate that address into google maps so it can direct you to that map tile.

Answer (score 0):

Use split and join functions.

var strAddress="22-40 W 77th St, New York, NY 10024";

strAddress = strAddress.split(' ').join('+');

This will replace all space with + sign, and you will get your desired output.

Comment: so.. run a regex, build an array, then turn the array back into a string? Why not just a straight up string replacement?

Comment: Marc, you are right. this code also works. However, this is also converted to  regex expression internally. strAddress = strAddress.replace(/ /gi, '+');